# is it possible for a function to have a removable discontinuity in the domain but doesn't have a removable discontinuity in the range?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

Sometimes removable discontinuities lie on one of the axis and sometimes it lies on any point on the graph.

My question is - if there is a removable discontinuity in the domain of a function does that implies that there should be a removable discontinuity in the range?

Comment: There's no such term like a "hole" in mathematics. Do you mean discontinuity?

Comment: @IshraaqParvez yes I'm referring to removable discontinuity

Comment: I just answered your question assuming you meant the domain was not either not connected or not simply connected.  A removable discontinuity is a property of the function, not of the domain alone

Comment: @CMonsour I know that a removable discontinuity is a property of the function, but does it always appear in the range of the function?

Comment: Are you looking for something like $f(x)=\frac{x^4-x^2}{x}$ which is defined on the domain $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, but the singularity at $x=0$ is in fact a removable one as $f$ can be extended to all of $\Bbb R$ via $\hat f(x)=x^3-x$. Note that both $f$ and $\hat f$ are onto $\Bbb R$, in particular, $f(-1)=f(1)=\hat f(0)=0$.

Comment: yes that what I was looking for thank you very much @HagenvonEitzen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  Let $f$ be a constant function.  Then the range has no holes, regardless of how many holes the domain has

Comment: I think I didn't use the correct word I'm referring to removable discontinuity, constant function doesn't have removable discontinuity

Comment: Yrs, but you can define a constant function on a domain with a hole, like $\Bbb{R}^2$ minus the unit disc.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAbdullah The constant function $x/x$ has a removable singularity at the origin.